# PWA shared localstorage with web

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I have a little problem with localstorage values shared between webpage and standalone homescreen app. It seems to be working good on Chrome, the data pushed to localstorage at first open is visible after adding it to homescreen. The problem occurs on iOS. I need to store unique per viewer token from param of URL. The "start_url" in manifest is set to '/'. I cannot put this token there. Had someone similar problem?